# add private hostname to dns

Tags: dns, osx-lion, hostname

I have an Apple OS X Lion server with the host name `server.company.private.` and an IP address of `10.1.10.11` on a router with an IP address of `10.1.10.1`.  We have many users (iMacs) on another router that we use for wireless which is `192.169.0.xxx` but when they type `server.company.private` it can't find the host. If you add the DNS server `10.1.10.11` to the network settings it works but I'd like to set it so any user connected to the wireless router `192.168.0.1` can access the server with the hostname.

What do I need to do to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you using DHCP or static addresses on the 192.168 network?

Comment: I believe DHCP.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick's solution should work, if you weren't using DHCP, AFAIK, you have to set the DNS manually on all machines.

Answer (score 1):

On your other router that is used for wireless, open up the administrative interface (usually a web-page at the router's IP-address) and find the DHCP settings, add the address of your DNS server (10.1.10.11) to the appropriate place.

Some home routers don't allow for this and always set themselves as the DNS server. In that case you'd have to run DHCP service from a different computer or replace the router with something that has the features you need.